# Как использовать переменную цикла в .bat файла в цикле for?

Tags: windows, bat

Имеется следующий код в .bat файле:

```
@echo off
set NAMEFILE=version

rem counting commas
set "f=%VERSION%"
set "vz=,"
set /a "z=0,n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /r /c:"\%vz%" "%f%"') do set "s=%%a"& call :#
<+ (for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ('more') do set /a "z+=%%b")& del+

set /a z =%z% + 1

rem цикл с проблемой
rem tokens=%%a* - часть кода, содержащая проблему
for /l %%a in (1,1,%z%) do for /f "tokens=%%a* delims=," %%i in (%NAMEFILE%) do @echo %%i>File_%%a.vers


:#
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 2>nul
  for %%a in ("!s:~%n%,1!") do (

   if "%%~a"=="%vz%" set /a z+=1
   if not "%%~a"=="" set /a n+=1& goto #
  )
 endlocal
exit /b
```

Я не знаю, что делать с `tokens=%%a`. Переменная `%%a` не видна во время выполнения (как я полагаю). Может быть проблема в символе `%`? Думаю, что он должен быть экранирован. Помогите, если знаете ответ.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Да, я задавал подобный вопрос на русском языке, мне никто не ответил. Решил, что если напишу на английском языке, то мне ответят быстрее, так как подтянется англоговорящий сегмент сообщества. Не заметил, что нахожусь в SO.ru. Перевожу. Проблема заключается в том, что в "tokens=%%a" переменная цикла %%а игнорируется и не вставляется. Не могу найти способ, как её экранировать. Или может существует другое решение. Я не знаю. Что угодно, лишь бы заработало.

Comment: @SergeyKrasilnikov, отредактируйте сам вопрос

Comment: Если %% не помагает, значит ставьте 4-ре %%%%. Надо внимательно пересмотреть код, и правильно расставить один %, два, и если нужно 4. Лучше указать какая строка у вас проблемная.

Comment: Мне на английской версии стаковерфлоу помогли уже. Переменную цикла нельзя использовать в качестве параметра цикла, как я понял. Решилась проблема хитрым путём. Пришлось завести новую функцию, которая является подциклом, и передавать параметр цикла в неё как аргумент.

Comment: Четыре %%%% вызвали ошибку.

Comment: Опубликуйте ответ, для повышения уровня нашей образованности

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя  использовать ни delayed expansion (не знаю аналог термина на русском), ни for-parameter expansion в части параметров команды FOR (то же самое верно  и для if). Это вызвано тем, как их обрабатывает пакетный парсер.

Но процентное расширение всё ещё работает. В моём пример нельзя использовать его встроенным (*inline*), поэтому приходится использовать вспомогательную функцию.

```
...
for /l %%a in (1,1,%z%) do call :helper_func %%a
...


:helper_func
for /f "tokens=%1* delims=," %%i in (%NAMEFILE%) do @echo %%i>File_%%a.vers
```

Выглядит странно, что в `helper_func` всё ещё можно использовать `%%a` в `echo %%i>File_%%a`. Это эффект того, что все используемые в данный момент параметры `for` видны во всех циклах `for`.

идея пользователя jeb

Answer (score 0):

Тоже искал решение и нашел, оказалось всё просто:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CHCP 1251
CLS
REM Организация цикла
SET BASES1C=(base1 base2 base3 base4)
FOR %%i IN %BASES1C% DO (
SET PGDATABASE=%%i
echo !PGDATABASE!
)
```